# Are there any built-in methods in java to arrange elements of array?

Tags: java

I encountered a question in my exam, which is to find the maximum and minimum values from an array of ints.
I was wondering if there is a way to arrange elements in ascending order. The first index should be minimum element and the last element the maximum element.

Comment: By sorting it...?

Comment: Sorting is an inefficient way to find max/min values of an array. Have you tried googling for "sorting an array in Java"?

Comment: you could simply use `int min = Collections.min(list);` and `int max = Collections.max(list);` (maybe convert the array to a list with `Arrays.asList(arr);`

Comment: `java.util.Arrays.sort(yourArray)`

Comment: Sorting an array is way overkill for finding the min and max value. All you need is to loop into the entire values and compare it from your min/max variables. It will just take you `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])) to sort every type of array. [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) to sort a list. So, yes there are some methods to sort arrays or collections.

But it'll be faster to do linear search instead of sorting, because linear search is `O(n)` and sorting is `O(n log n)` or worse (where `n` is the array's length).